# How in Faraday rotator, changing magnetic field will change the refractive index of RCP and LCP?

Tags: electromagnetism, refraction, magnetostatics, birefringence

Can anyone mathematically prove how in the faraday rotator, when we change the magnetic field direction, it will change the refractive index of Right circularly polarized (RCP) and Left circularly polarized light (LCP), meaning the refractive index of right circularly polarized light will become that of left and vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

In an externally biased ferrite the permeability is a non-symmetrical tensor and it can be derived the following way starting with $\mathbf B = \mu_0 (\mathbf H + \mathbf M)$ and since the torque on a dipole $\mathbf m $ is $\mathbf m \times \mathbf B $ and the angular momentum $\mathbf L$ is proportional to the dipole moment (assume lossless case), hence $\frac{d\mathbf L}{dt} = \gamma \mathbf m \times \mathbf B$ where $\gamma = q_e/m_e$ is the so-called gyromagnetic constant. Or written per unit volume  $\frac{d\mathbf M}{dt} = \gamma \mathbf M \times \mathbf B$ but since $\mathbf M \times \mathbf M =0$ we also have $$\frac{d\mathbf M}{dt} = \gamma \mu_0 \mathbf M \times \mathbf H$$
Now write the incident magnetic field as $\mathbf H = \mathbf H_0 + \mathbf H^{\pm}$ where $\mathbf H^{\pm}$ represent a small amplitude RF wave riding on the bias field (later this will be the RCP/LCP waves), and $|\mathbf H_0| >> |\mathbf H^{\pm}|$. After some expansion, linearization, simplification, etc., see e.g., Collin: Foundations of Microwave Engineering section 6.7., you get the following
$$\mathbf B= \mu_0 {\bar \mu} \mathbf H \tag{1}\label{1}$$
$$ \bar \mu=\begin {bmatrix}
1+\chi_{0} & \mathfrak j \kappa & 0\\
-\mathfrak j \kappa & 1+\chi_0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \tag{2}\label{2}$$
$$ \chi_0 =\omega_0\frac{\omega_m}{\omega_0^2-\omega_m^2}\\
\kappa = \omega \frac{\omega_m}{\omega_0^2-\omega_m^2} \tag{3}\label{3} \\
\omega_m = \mu_0 \gamma M_s\\ \omega_0 = \gamma H_0$$

For a TEM wave propagating along the $z$ axis $\mathbf E = \mathscr{E} e^{-\mathfrak j \beta z}$ and from Faraday's law of induction $\nabla \times \mathbf E = \mathfrak j \beta \mathscr{E} \times \hat {z} e^{-\mathfrak j \beta z} = -\mathfrak j \omega  \mu_0 \bar \mu \mathbf H = -\mathfrak j \omega \mu_0 \bar \mu \mathscr {H} e^{-\mathfrak j \beta z}$ that is
$$ \beta \mathscr{E} \times \hat {z} =  - \omega \mu_0 \bar \mu \mathscr {H} \tag {4}\label{4}$$
Similarly, Ampere's law gives $$ \beta \mathscr{H} \times \hat {z} =  \omega \epsilon \mathscr {E} \tag {5}\label{5}$$
and combing $\eqref{4}$ and $\eqref{5}$ you get $\beta^2 \mathscr{H} = \omega ^2 \mu_0\bar \mu \mathscr{H}$ or
$$(\beta^2 - \omega ^2 \mu_0\bar \mu) \mathscr{H} = 0 $$. This is a homogeneous linear system of equations in two unknowns $\mathscr{H}_x$ and $\mathscr{H}_y$,
$$ \begin {bmatrix}
\beta^2-\omega^2\mu_0(1+\chi) & -\mathfrak j \omega^2 \epsilon \mu_0 \kappa \\
\mathfrak j \omega^2 \epsilon \mu_0 \kappa & \beta^2-\omega^2\mu_0(1+\chi)
\end {bmatrix} 
\begin {bmatrix}
\mathscr{H}_x\\
\mathscr{H}_y \end {bmatrix} = 0 \tag{6}\label{6}$$
For $\eqref {6}$ have a non-trivial solution the system determinant must be zero:

$$ det \begin {bmatrix}
\beta^2-\omega^2\mu_0(1+\chi_0) & -\mathfrak j \omega^2 \epsilon \mu_0 \kappa \\
\mathfrak j \omega^2 \epsilon \mu_0 \kappa & \beta^2-\omega^2\mu_0(1+\chi_0)
\end {bmatrix} = 0 $$ and this gives two soultions:
$$\beta^{\pm}= \sqrt{\omega^2\mu_0(1+\chi_0) \pm  \omega^2 \epsilon \mu_0 \kappa} \tag{7}\label{7}$$
For both cases $\mathscr{H}_x/\mathscr{H}_y = \pm\mathfrak j$, in other words this propagating plane wave is in a circularly polarized mode, but its wavenumber depends  on the direction of its propagation: $$\beta^+ = \omega \sqrt{\epsilon \mu^+} \ne \beta^- = \omega \sqrt{\epsilon \mu^-} $$
where $\mu^{\pm} = \mu_0\big(1+\frac{\gamma M_s}{\omega_0 \pm \omega}\big)$!